# Why is the size of a composite hypothesis defined as a supremum and not an infimum?

Tags: statistics

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)):

> In the case of a composite hypothesis, the **size** is the supremum over all data generating processes that satisfiy the null hypotheses.
>
> $$\alpha = \sup_{h\in H_0} P(\text{test rejects } H_0 | h). $$

**Question:** It seems that defining the "size" in this way makes it easier for us to reject a null hypothesis (since we are maximizing the chances that an observation lands in the rejection region of a random variable). Wouldn't it make more sense to use an infimum here instead of a supremum to make a test as "harsh" as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **size** of a test is, loosely speaking, the maximum Type I error probability.  As the Wikipedia article put it, this is the probability of falsely rejecting the null.

Your misconception stems from a misinterpretation of $\alpha$:  here, we wish to **control** $\alpha$ to be **small**, not large.  A size $\alpha = 0.1$ test has at most a $10\%$ chance of incorrectly rejecting the null.  This is worse than a size $\alpha = 0.01$ test that has at most only a $1\%$ chance of Type I error; thus, by taking the supremum, you are indeed using the worst-case scenario.  The test is harsh not because it minimizes the (conditional) probability of rejecting $H_0$ in some way, but because in order for you to achieve a desired size for the test, you must decrease the rejection region of the test statistic in order to ensure that among all possible situations satisfying the null hypothesis, the worst-case probability of incorrectly rejecting $H_0$ is at most $\alpha$.